# jQuery Traversal Closest <div> of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to figure out some jQuery here. I've found some notes about jQuery traversal, but nothing seems to fit what I need.

This is a dummy that represents what I need. `<div class="parent">` would actually be the start of a comment from a forum - one of many on the page. There are several `<div>` tags as children inside it. Inside one of those `<div>` tags is a `<span>` that has a Hide button. I need that button to hide the next `<div class='specific-class'>` inside the `<div class="parent">`. The code below will always hide "Box 1" no matter which of the hide buttons I click. I could modify the code to give each comment a unique class, but I'd rather use some traversal magic to pick the right one.

Forgive the quickie code below, it's just here as a reference. :)

```js
$(".hideBtn").click(function() {
  var element = $("div.buttons").next(".hideable:first");
  if (element.hasClass("hidden")) {
    element.removeClass("hidden");
    element.slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    element.addClass("hidden");
    element.slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
.hideBtn {
  font-size: large;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #cecece;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hideBtn:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #bcbcbc;
}
.hideable {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 1</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 2</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 3</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

div `.hidable` is sibling of clicked buttons closest parent `div.buttons`. thus you need to traverse to `.buttons` and then use `.next()` to target the first `.hideable`:

```
var element = $(this).closest('.buttons').next();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ayfyb7r/)**

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple that I was missing. This reminds me of the headaches I used to feel when trying to create linked lists in C.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You just need to refer to the current `<a>` button that was clicked, then find it's parent `.buttons` and then find the next closest element with the class `.hideable`. Using the `next(".hideable")` ensures you will always hide the correct `<div class='hideable'>` even if there are more elements between the `.buttons` and `.hideable` containers

`$(this).closest(".buttons").next(".hideable");`

Example:

```js
$(".hideBtn").click(function(e) {
  var element = $(this).closest(".buttons").next(".hideable");
  if (element.hasClass("hidden")) {
    element.removeClass("hidden");
    element.slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    element.addClass("hidden");
    element.slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
.hideBtn {
  font-size: large;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #cecece;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hideBtn:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #bcbcbc;
}
.hideable {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 1</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 2</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 3</div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="hideBtn"><a href="#">HIDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box hideable">This is a hideable Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I picked the one above as it had an earlier time stamp, but your answer was also helpful. I'm new to stackoverflow, so if there's a way I can give you credit as well, please let me know.

Comment: No worries, I was mostly through posting so I thought I might as well post it as well because my answer had an additional possibly useful extra `.next(".hideable")`. As for credit, upvotes are generally used to indicate a useful answer :)